# NSInternalInconsistencyException error in UITableViewDelegate for deleting a cell / Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, swipe

I'd like to have two actions in swipe normal (it means right to left), in a table view in Xamarin.iOS.

As I searched, I know that I can customize a UITableViewDelegate for my table and have a swipe with different actions.

Here is my UITableViewDelegate code :

```
public class NotificationTableDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
{
    private readonly AlertsViewController _AlertsViewController;
    private List<NotificationItem> _notifications;

    public NotificationTableDelegate(AlertsViewController tagViewController, List<NotificationItem> notifs)
    {
        _AlertsViewController = tagViewController;
        _notifications = notifs;
    }

    public override UITableViewRowAction[] EditActionsForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewRowAction activateOrDeactivateNotifAction = UITableViewRowAction.Create(
            UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal,
            "activate",
            delegate {
                //activate or deactivate 
            }
        );

        UITableViewRowAction deleteNotifAction = UITableViewRowAction.Create(UITableViewRowActionStyle.Destructive,"Delete",async delegate
        {
            UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create(_notifications.ElementAt(indexPath.Row).Label, "ConfirmDeleteAlert", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Yes", UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, (action) => {
                _notifications.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
                tableView.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
            }));
            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, (action) => { }));
            await _AlertsViewController.PresentViewControllerAsync(alert, true);
        });
        return new UITableViewRowAction[] { deleteNotifAction, activateOrDeactivateNotifAction };

    }
}
```

There, I have two actions, "activate" and "delete". Until here, everything works fine BUT, the action for deleting makes me an error. 
When I delete a row and after accepting the removing, it makes me NSInternalInconsistencyException error :

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>   Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The
>   number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7)
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before
>   the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
>   from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number
>   of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

I think the error is correct, because the number of cells in Table must change, but in NotificationTableDelegate I have no access to items in UITableViewSource !! How can I resolve this error or how can I modify items in UITableViewSource ? Any idea?

*I have the code for having delete inside UITableViewSource by using CommitEditingStyle etc... and it's not in my case. 
In additional I have CanEditRow, true in UITableViewSource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Source` of tableview instead.

This class include all the methods in `UITableViewDelegate + UITableViewDataSource`